# Scroll to actual comment when clicking on comment notification in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Currently, when I click on a comment notification in the Android app, I simply get to the "answers-Tab".

I would expect that it also scrolls to the comment itself, especially for questions with lots of answers.

It is very bad if I have to search for the comment (and there seems not to be a possibility to search the page).

Comment: We don't even scroll to the correct *answer* yet when following an answer link :) But you're absolutely right, this should work eventually.

Comment: @balpha: eventually = 6-8 weeks? :)

Comment: Come on, it's 2015, and it's still not implemented?